# Where to use std::span?

Tags: c++, c++20, copy-elision, std-span

I want to write a function that can accept any type of contiguous buffer (e.g. `std::array`, `std::vector`, *raw array*, etc) from its call site. I have come up with two methods.

Method #1:

```
void func( int* const buffer, const std::size_t expectedTokenCount );
```

Here, `expectedTokenCount` is the maximum number of elements that will be inserted into the `buffer`.

Method #2:

```
void func( const std::span<int> buffer, const std::size_t expectedTokenCount );
```

In this approach, I think that I better write the function in a way that first checks the size of the `buffer` via `buffer.size( )` and compares it with `expectedTokenCount` to make sure that its capacity is greater than or equal to `expectedTokenCount` otherwise it throws some kind of exception. Is this a **valid and safer** method than the 1st method? Which one is better? Will the behavior of `span` and its `size` member function change if a vector is passed to it or will it be the same as for array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where to use std::span?

Where-ever you would have otherwise used a pointer and a size, you can use `std::span` instead of the pointer and the size.

> Is [#2] a valid ... method?

Sure. You did however change the constness of the pointer. You should use `std::span<const int>`.

> Which one is better?

Each have their uses. But in most cases passing two sizes is redundant

The use of `std::span` is orthogonal to the change of using two sizes. You can do #1 as `void(std::span<const int>)` and you can do #2 as `void(int* const buffer, const std::size_t buffer_size, const std::size_t expectedTokenCount)`.

Using `std::span` is generally an improvement.

Comment: So what do you think about my 2nd method and the exception throwing part? Is it ok to do that? Or should I for example just write a static_assert in the call site to check and compare the size of the `buffer` and `expectedTokenCount` before passing them to the `func`?

Comment: @digito_evo: Why do you need `expectedTokenCount` separate from the `span`'s `size`?

Comment: Or maybe an even safer way! I can pass the buffer to `func`  like { buffer.data(), expectedTokenCount  }. Is this better?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Good question. Essentially for better code readability inside the `func`'s body and also making it a bit more *foolproof*.

Comment: How does that make it more foolproof? It makes it less foolproof as now you have the responsibility of ensuring that the values are equal.